# Overlapping Associative Arrays

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

I need to overlap data from multiple associative arrays with the following considerations:

- If a matching key exists, overwrite it
- If a key exists but doesn't match, append new value to that element
- If neither of the above, create an element to store the value

Take for example the following structures:

```
 <?php

 for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
    $table["table_$i"] = array(
        "cell_0" => array(
        'row'     => 12,
        'column'  => 5
        )
    );
 }

 for ($i = 4; $i < 12; $i++) {
    $table["table_$i"] = array(
        "cell_0" => array(
        'row'     => 9,
        'column'  => 8
        )
    );
 }

 for ($i = 5; $i < 15; $i++) {
    $table["table_$i"] = array(
        "cell_1" => array(
        'row'     => 4,
        'column'  => 1
        )
    );
 }

 ?>
```

The desired output would look like this:

```
 {"table_0":{"cell_0":{"row":12,"column":5}},"table_1":{"cell_0":{"row":12,"column":5}},"table_2":{"cell_0":{"row":12,"column":5}},"table_3":{"cell_0":{"row":12,"column":5}},"table_4":{"cell_0":{"row":9,"column":8}},"table_5":{"cell_0":{"row":9,"column":8},"cell_1":{"row":4,"column":1}},"table_6":{"cell_0":{"row":9,"column":8},"cell_1":{"row":4,"column":1}},"table_7":{"cell_1":{"row":4,"column":1}},"table_8":{"cell_0":{"row":9,"column":8},"cell_1":{"row":4,"column":1}},"table_9":{"cell_0":{"row":9,"column":8},"cell_1":{"row":4,"column":1}},"table_10":{"cell_0":{"row":9,"column":8},"cell_1":{"row":4,"column":1}},"table_11":{"cell_0":{"row":9,"column":8},"cell_1":{"row":4,"column":1}},"table_12":{"cell_1":{"row":4,"column":1}},"table_13":{"cell_1":{"row":4,"column":1}},"table_14":{"cell_1":{"row":4,"column":1}}}
```

Take note from the desired output that the value of cell_0 doesn't replace the value of cell_1: I couldn't get the desired output using `array_merge()` in this case.

Any help would be appreciated--thanks!

Comment: array_merge_recursive?

Answer (score 1):

Check `array_merge` and `array_unique` php functions.